# Accessing S3 PrivateLink from CLI on a server that has no Internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have my corporate network connected to my AWS environment thru direct link. I have a Linux server which has no internet access but it can ping the private IPs of my EC2 instances. I also have a VPC Endpoint (PrivateLink) for S3.

When I issue a `aws s3 ls` from that server it is not able to connect to S3 to list my buckets. Is this because the server has no internet access? Is there no way around it?

Error message:

> ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Comment: `that server` is in corporate network or in AWS?

Comment: Are you asking how to run `aws s3 ls` from a computer on your corporate network (with no Internet access) such that it will go across an AWS Direct Connect link and go out a _VPC Endpoint (PrivateLink) for S3_ and therefore communicate with the S3 service?

Comment: Yes, correct. @JohnRotenstein. I can reach VPC services (like Redshift for instance using psql). But can't reach S3 even after I explicitly state region. The Access/Secret I have configured on that computer has access only to S3, not to EC2, not sure if that matters reaching the private link.